# How can I convert .obj files to .3ds on Mac?

Tags: file-format, macos

I am on a Mac. I am currently looking for a tool that is able to **correctly** convert  .obj files (Wavefront) to .3ds files (Autodesk 3ds Max).

I tried Blender but the exported file failed to include the smoothing groups.

What do you recommend I use?

Comment: Which technology to use questions are off topic for the site. Refresh yourself with the [FAQ].

Comment: @Byte56 This isn't a "which technology should I use?" question.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs Well, it still kind of is. If it fully listed requirements it might be able to get by. However, there's only a passing mention of smoothing groups, but no other indicators as to what "**correctly**" means. Your edit makes it better, but I still think it fails to provide enough information to get anything other than a list of tools to use.

Comment: @Byte56 There is a requirement here: it converts correctly without skipping stuff. It's a "I need to do this, how can I do it?" question that may well have multiple answers, but it isn't the sort of question you get in "which technology?" questions.

Comment: @JonathanHobbs OK. Fair enough. The way it was originally worded still makes me believe the OP was asking for a list of tools to use. But I'll remove my down vote because of your edits.

Comment: @Byte56 He probably was, as a subpar way of asking for what he was really after.

Comment: I don't think it's a problem for this specific question, but "correctly" is not generally a strict enough requirement for me, since there are usually many different perfectly correct methods. I don't think this question is constructive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [link to the autodesk docs](http://docs.autodesk.com/3DSMAX/15/ENU/3ds-Max-Help/index.html?url=files/GUID-7A9535E6-235D-459B-B32D-5A9E5E4EBF28.htm,topicNumber=d30e521345) about importing .obj files in 3ds Max.  The .3ds file format isn't something open and it's really tied to the internal workings of 3ds Max, so you can't really count on an external exporter or something like that.

Source: I worked on 3ds Max.